# Python(String): Using a string saved in a DataFrame cell as a pandas Formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe `InputDF` shown below.
It has only one column `Col1` (the 0'th column), whose values are all string:

[image]

I am trying to use the values in column 0 as a formula in pandas (mentioned below)
I have another empty data frame `DF2`where I try the following to insert data:

```
DF2 = InputDF.loc[0,0]
```

...this comes to `DF2["column1"] = 'p_input[Order No]'`

I need this to be `DF2["column1"] = p_input[Order No]`
so that I can save data available in "Order No" column of `p_input` dataframe in "columns1" column of "DF2" dataframe

[Note: p_input is another dataframe, due to some issues these assumptions can not change]

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` is your friend: `DF2 = eval(p_input[Line Of Business])`

Comment: now when 
DF2 = eval(p_input[Line Of Business]*20%)
this gives SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing for "%" at the end

Comment: Debugging this is great exercise, you're doing yourself a disfavor asking for help instead of sitting down and figuring it out yourself.